# looking for db2 text function or method I can do a text contain rather than like

Tags: sql, db2

I'm looking for a db2 function that does a text contain search. At present I am running the following query against the data below....

[image]

```
         SELECT distinct 
             s.search_id, 
             s.search_heading, 
             s.search_url 
         FROM repman.search s, repman.search_tags st
         WHERE s.search_id = st.search_id 
         AND ( UPPER(s.search_heading) LIKE (cast('%REPORT%' AS VARGRAPHIC(32))) 
                OR (UPPER(st.search_tag)  LIKE cast('%REPORT%' AS VARGRAPHIC(32))) 
              )
         ORDER BY s.search_heading;
```

Which returns...

[image]

But if I change the search text to %REPORTS% rather than %REPORT% (which I need to do) the like search does not work and I get zero results.

I read a link that used a function named CONTAINS like below but when trying to use the function I get an error.

```
         SELECT distinct 
             s.search_id, 
             s.search_heading, 
             s.search_url 
         FROM repman.search s, repman.search_tags st
         WHERE s.search_id = st.search_id 
                     AND CONTAINS(s.search_heading, 'REPORTS') = 1
```

[image]

Has anynoe got any suggestions? I'm on db2 version DB2/LINUXPPC 9.1.6.

Thanks

Comment: As the error message says, you need to install and configure Net Search Extender.

Answer (score 1):

In order to look for a pattern in a string, you can use Regular Expressions. They are built-in DB2 with xQuery since DB2 v9. There are also other ways to do that. I wrote an [article](http://angocadb2.blogspot.fr/2014/04/regular-expressions-in-db2.html) in my blog (in Spanish that you can translate) about Regular Expressions in DB2.

```
xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches(\$TEXT,''^[A-Za-z 0-9]*$'')')
```